Istio VirtualService and DestinationRule ignored when calling a service from inside the mesh
I am trying to implement blue/green deployment using Istio virtual services and destination rules. Seems like I can make it work when calling from outside the cluster, but when a pod calls another pod the requests are balanced on both blue and green instances. All the pods involved have the Envoy sidecar.
Istio ingress gateway has been installed with the default istioctl install.
The other relevant manifests are the following:
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: bg-gateway
  namespace: bluegreen-playground
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 8080
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - bluegreen.myexample.com

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: bg-route
  namespace: bluegreen-playground
spec:
  gateways:
    - bg-gateway
  hosts:
  - bluegreen.myexample.com
  - core-svc.bluegreen-playground.svc.cluster.local
  - front-svc.bluegreen-playground.svc.cluster.local
  http:
  - name: core
    match: 
    - uri:
        prefix: "/core"
    route:
    - destination:
        host: core-svc.bluegreen-playground.svc.cluster.local
        subset: blue
  - name: front
    match: 
    - uri: 
        prefix: "/"
    route:
    - destination:
        host: front-svc.bluegreen-playground.svc.cluster.local
        subset: blue

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: core-destination
  namespace: bluegreen-playground
spec:
  host: core-svc.bluegreen-playground.svc.cluster.local
  subsets:
  - name: blue
    labels:
      version: v1
  - name: green
    labels:
      version: v2

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: front-destination
  namespace: bluegreen-playground
spec:
  host: front-svc.bluegreen-playground.svc.cluster.local
  subsets:
  - name: blue
    labels:
      version: v1
  - name: green
    labels:
      version: v2

All the pods are correctly labeled with version: v1 or version: v2. The microservices call each other by using the standard Kubernetes service FQDN (e.g. front-svc.bluegreen-playground.svc.cluster.local).
Am I missing anything?

can you try adding - mesh under gateways section of VirtualService(line number 9) and test once?.

This solved the issue, if you post it as an answer I will accept it

As discussed, you need to add mesh to gateway selector in VirtualService to apply the same rules inside mesh.
https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#VirtualService-gateways.

The names of gateways and sidecars that should apply these routes.
Gateways in other namespaces may be referred to by /; specifying a gateway with no namespace
qualifier is the same as specifying the VirtualService’s namespace. A
single VirtualService is used for sidecars inside the mesh as well as
for one or more gateways. The selection condition imposed by this
field can be overridden using the source field in the match conditions
of protocol-specific routes. The reserved word mesh is used to imply
all the sidecars in the mesh. When this field is omitted, the default
gateway (mesh) will be used, which would apply the rule to all
sidecars in the mesh. If a list of gateway names is provided, the
rules will apply only to the gateways. To apply the rules to both
gateways and sidecars, specify mesh as one of the gateway names.

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: bg-route
  namespace: bluegreen-playground
spec:
  gateways:
    - bg-gateway
    - mesh # applies to all the sidecars in the mesh
  hosts:
  - bluegreen.myexample.com
  - core-svc.bluegreen-playground.svc.cluster.local
  - front-svc.bluegreen-playground.svc.cluster.local
  http:
  - name: core
    match: 
    - uri:
        prefix: "/core"
    route:
    - destination:
        host: core-svc.bluegreen-playground.svc.cluster.local
        subset: blue
  - name: front
    match: 
    - uri: 
        prefix: "/"
    route:
    - destination:
        host: front-svc.bluegreen-playground.svc.cluster.local
        subset: blue

